# Move and rename picture with Intervention/image module

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, image-uploading, intervention

I'm using 'Intervention/image' module , have two folders , i want to move and rename image .

`public/temp/image1.png` to `public/my-folder/my-image.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run simply php rename function

`rename("/public/temp/image1.png", "/public/my-folder/my-image.png");`

[php rename manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Answer (score 3):

It does seems that **Intervention Image** is doing the actual upload. So in this case you will have to use [Filesystem's method move](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_move) (check out the rest of the methods for more available functionality).

Example:

```
if (!File::move($old, $new)) {
    // Display an error
}
```